# Not all arguments converted during string formatting Python Online Compiler

Tags: python

So this morning, after finishing some school work I decided I wanted to make a joke app type 'thing' for my friends to check out, so i set out to program a little "Desktop Virtual Assistant", now it isn't as easy as I thought it would be in fact I have tried this several times and failed or given up every time, well not this time. So when I started to make the naming function of it I get this error "not all arguments converted during string formatting"

and this is my code.

```
def start():
    print("Welcome to your Destop Virtual Assistant")
    name = input("Please give me a name.")
    print("My name is now >>>" %name)
start()
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the string [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) method.

```
def start():
    print("Welcome to your Destop Virtual Assistant")    
    name = input("Please give me a name.")
    print("My name is now >>> {}".format(name))
```

Or you can just use the `+` operator since you are concatenating two strings.

```
print("My name is now >>> " + name)
```

Comment: thanks, I completely forgot you could simply add variable to it. atleast without getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
print("My name is now >>> ", name)
```

If you'd like to use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-examples) do it like this:

```
print("My name is now >>> {}".format(name))
```